# How do I block Safari users from my website?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

I would like to block all users of Safari from visiting my flash game web site.  I would like them to see a picture of someone being punched in the face instead of the games.

My understanding is that you can use JavaScript to do it, but I don't want to use some heavy framework like JQuery.  Is there a way to do it in like a single line or two of JavaScript?

Comment: If you would just use JQuery, I'm pretty sure you could *actually* punch them in the face instead of only showing a picture of someone being punched in the face.

Comment: Umm...that's pretty heavy handed, blocking all Safari users and showing a picture of being punched in the face. Not that I should be using SO to promote my sociopolitical ideals, but I'm sure at least most people here would agree

Comment: Why do you wanna block safari users from a Flash game? Wouldn't Flash run well in Safari? Anyways, you should totally drop this and use jQuery instead.

Comment: Also, I know this isn't quite relevant to your question, but WHY?

Comment: You do know that not all Safari users are on the iPhone, right?

Comment: So you run the only site that has not in mind as collateral main purpose to attract more and more users... Odd. I would "spoof" the user agent someway to let me use your site even with Safari... provided that it has contents I'd like to access to (also with Safari).

Comment: I use Safari on the Mac and you know what? I don't want to visit your poxy game site anyway, so there! :-P

Comment: if the issue is e.g. iPhone can't run Flash (very happy of this I am, indeed...), then the use of object tag will give you a way to show alternative content if flash is not supported, like many sites using flash already do (no need to identify the browser lacking the flash support)

Comment: By the way, there was a guy who ran some political blog who decided that Adblock users were thieves and blocked them from his websites, and encouraged others to do likewise. Pretty much everyone [thought he was a moron](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20070817/143014.shtml). For good reason, I might suggest.

Comment: You do realize that insulting people will most definitely not convince them of anything. Especially not of something that ridiculous. How would you feel if some website blocks your browser/device and insults you for no reason?

Comment: Seriously, I am using Firefox, would you give me your website url so I can start playing the Flash game now? Oh...NO...I installed AdBlock...

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: "see a picture of someone being punched in the face instead of the games"--that's fairly hilarious.  I mean failarious.

Comment: Someone needs to create an `IAmADick.js` library for stuff like this.

Comment: -1. Sorry, but this is utterly dumb and completely misses the point. Lots of people complain about Apple's draconian policies (and rightly so, if you ask me) because they create artificial restrictions for their users; restrictions based on Apple's bussiness strategy, not technical reasons. The whole point is removing these artificial barriers, not adding new ones.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a horrible, horrible idea IMO. I can understand the sentiment, but this is going to do as much good, and raise as much sympathy, as sites with "Stop using IE, moron!" messages. But it's up to you....

Quirksmode has a small [BrowserDetect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) library that I trust has all the quirks worked out. If I were you, I would use that.

To do it in one line, look for `Safari` in the `navigator.userAgent` string.

Example code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari/') != -1){
 alert("Safari detected");
}
```

If you want to make 100% sure you catch them all (well, 99% bearing in mind the user agent string can be changed freely by the client), you'd need to use a server-side language like PHP.

```
if (strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Safari")) 
 {
  header("location:no-safari.html");
  die();
 }
```

Comment: +1 for *"horrible, horrible idea"*.  These types of "ideas" were particularly annoying for users who couldn't choose their web browser.  Unfortunately, it is the will of some people to punish the users because a foolish/delusional view that the browser vendor will actually care.

Comment: @Andy E yup. I'm all for protesting against Apple's policies - I find many of them horrible and unethical, too -  but harassing your users isn't going to help. Never has.

Comment: Thanks a million!

This is perfect - by adding window.location="no-safari.html" instead of alert it moves the page too!

Comment: You can make this cleaner by not checking for iPad/iPhone/and iPod touch Safari user agent strings.

Comment: "If you want to make 100% sure" << It doesn't make it 100%.  You can very easily change the user agent string to whatever you like.

Comment: @Oli I mean, 100% sure in normal circumstances (i.e. when JavaScript is turned off.) It is still worth mentioning, good point, will edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(navigator.appName == "Safari")
{
....your code goes ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More than a couple of lines but you could very simply cut this down so it only bothers with Safari: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

A slightly more solid method would be to use a server-side detection method like php's [`get_browser([string $user_agent  [,  bool $return_array = false  ]])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Needless to say, this is all a bit silly.